# I'm trying to get this simple vanilla JS work in IE11/10

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

The script works everywhere but IE, I tried to google about it but all I could find is that forEach is not supported by IE, but I am not sure what loop to use to repalce this. Can someone help with this? Here is the code:

```
const liwraps  = document.querySelectorAll('.subpage-menu-li.submenu_has_children');

    liwraps.forEach(function(liwrap){
    const arwdrp = liwrap.querySelector('.arrow-drop'),
        ulsub  = liwrap.querySelector('.subpage-submenu-ul'),
        ulsubp = ulsub.parentElement

        if(ulsubp.classList.contains('current_page_item', 'current_page_parent') || ulsubp.classList.contains('current_page_parent')){
            ulsub.classList.add('active-subpage-submenu');
            arwdrp.classList.add('rotaten');
        }
        if(arwdrp){  
            arwdrp.addEventListener("click", function(){
            ulsub.classList.toggle('active-subpage-submenu');
            arwdrp.classList.toggle('rotaten');
            });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal for loop.

```
for (var i = 0, n = liwraps.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var liwrap = liwraps[i];
    // your function code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked as intended.